# Heroku: Push rejected, no Cedar-supported

Tags: git, meteor, heroku

I've made a Meteor app and have just discovered Heroku, where I want to deploy it.

My app Git is currently hosted on Bitbucket, but `git push heroku master` gets denied with following message:

> Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

I tried `git add remote` with my app details, but it's already added.

Should Heroku have it's own Git, inside my original Git?

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at you `.gitignore` file in the project directory.

If it has `.meteor` in it, remove it and try pushing again.

This should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

> "Heroku error message no Cedar-supported app detected"

I spent some time to sort it the solution can be found here

http://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/heroku-error-message-no-cedar-supported-app-detected/

Firstly, You need to cd in to your project directory

Do the following: `cd path/to/root/of/your/project` and try the command again.

Reinitializing your .git files:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Reinitialize"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```